# Given any group $G$ of order $12$, and any $n$ that divides $12$, there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

True or false: Given any group $G$ of order $12$, and any $n$ that divides $12$, there exists a subgroup $H$
of $G$ of order $n$.

Now we know that $D_{12}=<r,s|r^6=1=s^2, rs=sr^{-1}>$ has a subgroup $<r^2>$ of order $3$ and a subgroup $\{1,r^3,s,sr^3\}$ of order $4$. But is this true in general?

Comment: Do you mean "order" or "index" in the second paragraph of your question?

Comment: $D_{12}$ does have a subgroup of order $3$. Since $D_{12} = \langle  a,x \mid a^6 = x^2 =e, xax = a^{-1} \rangle$, we can clearly see that $\langle a^2 \rangle$ has order $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Sylow's Theorem any group of order $12$ has a subgroup of order $3$ and also a subgroup of order $4$.  Any subgroup of order $4$ itself has a subgroup of order $2$ -- either it is cyclic of order $4$ (in which case the square of a generator has order $2$) or *all* of its nonidentity elements have order $2$.

So the only remaining issue is whether there's a subgroup of order $6$.  $A_4$ has order $12$ but no subgroups of order $6$.  Any such subgroup would have to be nonabelian (because the only abelian group of order $6$ is $\Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$ and $A_4$ has no elements of order $6$) and therefore isomorphic to $S_3$.

But $S_3 \not \subseteq A_4.$  (As Marc van Leeuwen points out in the comments, one way to see this is that  any two elements of $A_4$ that have order $2$ commute with each other, a statement that is not true of $S_3$.)

Comment: I had literally exactly the same answer (even the same words) when I noticed that you wrote it first. Obviously I upvoted this.

Comment: I suppose $S_3\not\subseteq A_4$ means $A_4$ has no subgroup _isomorphic to_ $S_3$, which is something that needs a bit of checking. One argument is that in $A_4$ all elements of order $2$ mutually commute, which is not true in $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.